# Practicing Seifert van Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am just practicing how to use Seifert-van Kampen. The following excercise is from Hatcher, p.53.

> Let $X$ be the quotient space of $S^2$ obtained by identifying the
>   north and south poles to a single point. Put a cell complex structure
>   on $X$ and use this to compute $\pi_1(X)$.

I found a cell complex structure for $S^2$ with two points $e^0_1$, $e^0_2$ and a line $e^1$, and a disc $e^2$. Then I identify both points, such that one remains. I choose open neighbourhoods around  $e^1$ and $e^2$, let`s call them $U(e^1)$ and $U(e^2)$, then apply Seifert van Kampen with those as the subsets. Then just $\pi_1(U(e^1))$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, and the other group $\pi_1(U(e^2))$  is trivial.

So now the contributions from the intersection $U(e^1)\cap U(e^2)$ are trivial and we get $\mathbb{Z}$ for the fundamental group. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question illustrates the compelling case to use groupoids and the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points. In particular we take the $2$-sphere $S^2$ and the North and South poles $n,s$, say. Let $A$ be the set consisting of $n,s$. Then the fundamental groupoid $G = \pi_1(S^2,A)$ has only one arrow $\iota: n \to s$.

Now we can talk about identifying $n,s$ in the groupoid $G$ to a point $p$, say.  This gives a pushout of groupoids 
$$\begin{matrix}
A & \to & \{p\}\\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
G & \to & H
\end{matrix}$$
(We regard $A$ and $\{p\}$ as the same as the sets of identities in the groupoids.) An easy universal argument gives that $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, the additive group of integers. That is, using groupoids means you immediately get a model of the topology.

Full details of this kind of argument are given in the book [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html), T&G, whose first edition with these ideas was in 1968.

Note that since groupoids can be seen as having structure in dimensions $0$ and $1$, we can consider identifications in dimension $0$, which gives additional flexibility to geometric and topological applications, such as that in the question. See for example this [mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one).

Grothendieck wrote in his 1984 "Esquisse d'un Pogramme" (English translation):

" ..,people still obstinately persist,  when calculating with fundamental groups, in fixing a single base point, instead of cleverly choosing a whole packet of points which is invariant under  the symmetries of the situation, which thus get lost on the way.  In certain situations (such as descent theorems for fundamental groups `a la van  Kampen) it is much more elegant,  even indispensable for understanding  something, to work with fundamental groupoids with respect to a suitable    packet of base points,.."

I conjecture that one reason for this neglect is that people are unaware of the techniques for computing with groupoids. One of the constructions developed by Philip Higgins in his book [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html) is to consider for groupoids  pushouts of the form 
$$\begin{matrix} X & \xrightarrow{f} & Y \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
G & \to &H
\end{matrix}
 $$
where $X=Ob (G), Y=Ob(H)$ and $f:X \to Y$ is a function, and the downarrows are essentially inclusions of identities. Higgins writes $H$ as $U_f(G)$ but a convenient notation is also $f_*(G)$. This is related to the groupoid van Kampen Theorem in T&G, 9.1.2 (Corollary 3), p.343.  The explicit construction of $f_*(G)$ generalises the construction of free groups and of  free products of groups.

Oct 12, 2015 Actually the question does ask about cell structures. The following Figure 7.9 from T&G should help:

[image: modified sphere]

The left figure shows the sphere with antipodal points identified. It is clear that this is a torus $T= S^1 \times S^1$ with an inner circle shrunk to a point. But $T$ has a cell decomposition as $e^0 \cup e^1 \cup e^1 \cup e^2$ and so the shrinking kills one of the $e^1$.

The right hand figure shows  the "homotopy identification" $Y$ of $n,s$ by adding a line.  That space $Y$ is clearly homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^2$.

For more background on groupoids in algebraic topology see also this [presentation](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/galway7.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this problem on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem) for the theorem.

More generally, if you can recognize something as a [wedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) there is an easy way to apply the theorem -- the fundamental group is the free product of the wedge components:

"Van Kampen's theorem gives certain conditions (which are usually fulfilled for well-behaved spaces, such as CW complexes) under which the fundamental group of the wedge sum of two spaces X and Y is the free product of the fundamental groups of X and Y."

Comment: I just see the 2-sphere there with no points identified, which has trivial fundamental group